# Get the last 7 days' data count day by day from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to get past 7 day data counts day by day, from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59. My expected output is;

```
{
"2024-01-10":15,
"2024-01-09":25,
...
}
```

My sample data,

```
{
  "_id": "XXXXX",
  "action": "incoming",
  "createdAt": "2024-01-07T19:43:43.651Z"
}
```

I did it like this, and it works but it slowed down my project. Tried to do it with Aggregation but I couldn't do it.

```
for ( let i = 7; i >= 1;i-- ){
            let d1 = fns.subDays(new Date(),i);
            let result = await Actions.countDocuments({
                createdAt:{
                    $gte: fns.startOfDay(d1),
                    $lte: fns.endOfDay(d1),
                },
                action:"incoming"
            });
            weeklyIncoming.push(result);
        }
```

I think I should do it with Aggregation but as I said I'm confused. fns is date-fns package. Thank you for help.